# response.sendredirect in post method

Tags: javascript, jsp

response.sendredirect can we use this in Post method .?

Comment: it will be in get methohd na i need to use it in post method in a javascript function

Comment: What `Post` method? Where is `response.sendredirect` defined? Your question is missing some details.

Comment: if a use response redirect("url") in one page in the next page the parameter comes in which method post or get method ..?

Comment: What technology is the `response.redirect` coming from. I am assuming ASP.NET, but there is **nothing** in your question or tags that suggests that. Please add tags to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you can't use post method with response.sendRedirect. There are other way doing this if you intend not to display the variable into URL.

See some same question about this that may help you:

- [Related question1](http://hateinterview.com/java/how-can-i-make-a-post-request-through-response-sendredirect-or-response-setstatus-and-response-setheader-methods/5284.html)
- [Related question2](http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/sendredirect-using-post-48616.html)